# GWT 2.6 Supporting markdown

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I am working on a GWT project and I would like to add support for markdown. So far, I have tried *Showdown* editor, which despite that it works out of the box it lacks a toolbar. As a result, I am trying to use *Pagedown* but I cannot instantiate the editor.

What I have done so far... there is an abstract base class (that extends TextArea), which injects the Pagedown scripts from its contructor:

```
protected MarkdownEditorBase() {
    ScriptInjector.fromUrl("pagedown/Markdown.Converter.js")
        .setRemoveTag(false)
        .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
        .inject();

    ScriptInjector.fromUrl("pagedown/Markdown.Sanitizer.js")
        .setRemoveTag(false)
        .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
        .inject();

    ScriptInjector.fromUrl("pagedown/Markdown.Editor.js")
        .setRemoveTag(false)
        .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
        .inject();

    dock = new FlowPanel();
    FlowPanel wmdPanel = new FlowPanel();
    wmdPanel.setStyleName("wmd-panel");

    FlowPanel wmdButtonBar = new FlowPanel();
    wmdButtonBar.setStyleName("wmd-button-bar");

    setStyleName("wmd-input");
    this.getElement().setId("wmd-input");

    wmdPanel.add(wmdButtonBar);
    wmdPanel.add(this);

    dock.setStyleName("markdown-container");

    dock.add(wmdPanel);
    }
```

Then there is a native method to instantiate the editor and use it (as per demo instructions):

```
public native JavaScriptObject initEditor() /*-{
    var converter = new $wnd.Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    var editor = new $wnd.Markdown.Editor(converter);
    if (editor) {
        editor.run();
    }
    return editor;
}-*/;
```

Whenever I run this method from my extender class,

```
public PagedownEditor() {
    super();
    this.pagedownEditor = initEditor();
}
```

I get the following:

**Firebug console window**

```
TypeError: output is undefined
Markdown.Editor = function (markdownConverter, idPostfix, options) {
Markdown.Editor.js (line 92)

ReferenceError: Markdown is not defined
Markdown.Editor = function (markdownConverter, idPostfix, options) {
Markdown.Editor.js (line 92)
```

**Development Mode in Eclipse**

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError)
@com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava
/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)([JavaScript object(2344), JavaScript 
object(2343), JavaScript object(2360)]): $wnd.Markdown is undefined
```

Btw, I am using classic dev mode in GWT as with the super dev mode there were some conflicts and the project could not run.

Any help is warmly welcomed!

Comment: The first line should be `var converter = $wnd.Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();`, so no `new`, but I doubt that this is causing your problem.

Comment: @Baz Thank you for the fast reply. I did as you suggested but the problem still persists. Still getting "$wnd.Markdown is undefined".However, I tried to instantiate the editor at a later point and got this instead: "$wnd.Markdown.Editor is not a constructor"

Comment: How are you calling `new PagedownEditor()`? If you are doing it synchronously, those script tags might not have loaded yet (use the ScriptInjector callbacks). And if you just those scripts loaded unconditionally on app startup, consider putting them in your original html page, or loading them as TextResources into the app itself and injecting them directly instead of waiting for them to load.

Comment: Good point! Yes, I had the same suspicion about synchronicity. I followed your advice and extended ClientBundle got the text for the JS files and injected them with "fromString". Now it got a bit further and it throws this exception: 
*com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)([JavaScript object(2631), JavaScript object(2630), JavaScript object(2651)]): elem is null*. It feels like a pit of snakes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the really helpful comments. I decided to stick the TextResources method as the Pagedown source files are quite "heavy" and take a while to load. Nevertheless, the latest exception I was getting (elem is null) was mainly due to incorrect settings of the DIVs. In any case, here is the resources class to solve the problem:

```
interface PagedownResources extends ClientBundle {

    @Source("../../resources/pagedown/Markdown.Converter.js")
    TextResource markdownConverter();

    @Source("../../resources/pagedown/Markdown.Sanitizer.js")
    TextResource markdownSanizer();

    @Source("../../resources/pagedown/Markdown.Editor.js")
    TextResource markdownEditor();

    @Source("../../resources/pagedown/pagedown.css")
    TextResource markdownCSS();
}
```

Also, the CSS file was not part of the source, you can get it from the [demo folder](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/#hg%2Fdemo%2Fbrowser) and modify it accordingly.

To complete the answer, this is the rewritten constructor:

```
private PagedownResources mPagedownResourcesInstance = GWT.create(PagedownResources.class);

public PagedownEditor() {

    StyleInjector.inject(mPagedownResourcesInstance.markdownCSS().getText());
    ScriptInjector.fromString(mPagedownResourcesInstance.markdownConverter().getText())
        .setRemoveTag(false)
        .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();
    ScriptInjector.fromString(mPagedownResourcesInstance.markdownSanizer().getText())
        .setRemoveTag(false)
        .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();
    ScriptInjector.fromString(mPagedownResourcesInstance.markdownEditor().getText())
        .setRemoveTag(false)
        .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).inject();     

    mainContainer = new SimplePanel();
    Element wmdPanel = DOM.createDiv();
    wmdPanel.addClassName("wmd-panel");

    Element wmdButtonBar = DOM.createDiv();
    wmdButtonBar.setId("wmd-button-bar");

    Element wmdtextArea = DOM.createTextArea();
    wmdtextArea.addClassName("wmd-input");
    wmdtextArea.setId("wmd-input");

    wmdPanel.appendChild(wmdButtonBar);
    wmdPanel.appendChild(wmdtextArea);

    mainContainer.setStyleName("markdown-container");
    mainContainer.getElement().appendChild(wmdPanel);
    initWidget(mainContainer);
}
```

The only thing that is left to make Pagedown work is to override the `onLoad()` method (I am extending Composite) and invoke `initEditor()` in the method.

Have fun and thank you.